# can't create a component using Angular CLI

Tags: typescript, angular10

When i try to  create a new component using angular cli it gives an error: /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory,
i tried sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
But it did't work it showed this error:
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/node': File exists,
I am using Linux mint version 20

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Linux  may be this will works..

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

which install package binaries to /usr/bin/..

Comment: when i run this commad it shows this : ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/node': File exists